# what does the word "comprised" mean in this context? + a question about collocation

Tags: meaning, collocation

1- I found this on the CNN web page:

> "We request the FBI open an immediate investigation to determine if these reports are accurate and to explore the extent to which information and sources may have been comprised," reads the letter from Democratic Reps. Ted Lieu, Gerald Connolly, Donald Beyer, Pramila Jayapal, Peter Welch and Ruben Gallego.

[CNN: House Democrats call for FBI to probe into Kushner's ties to Saudi crown prince](https://edition.cnn.com/2018/03/29/politics/house-democrats-kushner-saudi-prince/index.html)

What does "comprised" mean here?

2- Can I use the word "run-ran" with "rumor"? e.g.,

> a rumor ran that the minister has an affair.

Comment: It's a typo or mistake for *compromised*.

Comment: Please don't ask unrelated questions in the same question.

Comment: I think I've heard the phrase "rumor running around" or "rumor going around", but  not sure about "rumor ran".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because (a) there are two questions, (b) one merely concerns a typo, and (c) the other lacks any evidence of research (eg Google Ngrams).

Answer (score 0):

**Comprised** in this context means that the author and editor of this article don't to how to spell ***compromised***. (A joke, it is a common typo)

For #2, it works if **ran** refers to running a story. It is fairly clunky though, I would suggest rewording it. ***Spread*** is what I would use if it is not in reference to a story.

PS In the future, do this as 2 posts.